# why a variable effects on other arraylist that's valuated before?

Tags: java, arraylist

i have huge code so i can't copy all of them and i'm sorry about that.

but i get some important parts.

i have a class 'Box' that can get value '0' or '1' and i have 'boxes' that is an arraylist of 'Box' that

is update in the code all the time. and i have another class 'state' that is an arraylist of 'Box' and

some other things and i want to use it for backtracking.

we can consider 'boxes' as the map of the program and 'state' saving 'boxes' in it.

so i have an arraylist of 'state' named 'states' to save all 'boxes' are made in each step during the code to get back if necessary.

i have a method to valuating boxes and i call it in a while loop.

i don't understand why when i create new instance of 'state' and add current 'boxes' to it, the value of 'state' is change with changing 'boxes' in code !!!!

even i create independent variable 'state st2' out of 'while loop' to check out what's happening and i saw 'st2' is changing too. and valuate it just once at first of the code.

```
state st1 = new state();
st1.setBoxes(boxes);
```

in other words we have some 'state' in 'states' that all of them change to last state and can not save their own value.

for better cosncepte

at first i add one state i have

```
st1
```

in 'states'

next time i add another 'state' like 'st2' to 'states'

and i have

```
st2 , st2
```

next time:

```
st3 , st3 , st3
```

how can i fix it?

i also create new 'ArrayList' of 'Box' and assign 'boxes' to it but not working.

i also create new 'state' in each step but that was not working too.
any body can help me to fix it?
if you have any ambiguity or miss understanding with my problem comment and i will answer it.
and if you have better way please tell me.

thanks

Comment: When using English, it is much easier to understand if you use capital letters properly.

Comment: @NomadMaker yes :)))) sorry

Answer (score 1):

All object variables are references. They are treasure maps. When you write:

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then `new ArrayList<String>()` creates new treasure and buries it in the sand. `List<String> x` describes a treasure map that you've created, and the `=` in the middle means x now is a map to the treasure you just buried. **x is the name of the map, *not* the treasure**. Treasure has no name.

```
setBoxes(x);
```

Remember, x is a treasure map that leads to treasure. It is not, itself, the treasure. Thus, this makes a copy of your treasure map and hands it to the `setBoxes` method. It doesn't make a copy of the treasure chest at all, though. 2 maps, but they lead to the same place. If setBoxes is:

```
public void setBoxes(List<Box> boxes) {
    this.boxes = boxes;
}
```

Then the object you called setBoxes on has a field, and, well, in java, it's all treasure *maps*. That field is now also a map to.. still that same one treasure. If you make a bunch more of these objects, then they all have their own copy of the treasure *map*, but all maps lead to the same treasure. So if one of them then does:

```
boxes.add("Hello");
```

Well, the dot (`.`) is the dereference operator: The 'follow this map and dig down' operator. This addition will thus be visible to **everybody** - everybody has a map to the same treasure, after all. If someone else later follows their copy, they get to the same treasure chest, so they see that Hello was added to it.

The solution is to start copying the treasure, not just the maps:

```
List<Box> copy = new ArrayList<Box>();
copy.addAll(boxes);
```

NOW you have two treasures, each identical. `boxes` is a map to one of them. `copy` is a map to the other.

Comment: thanks for your complete explainations.i tried that but  i think problem is that when 'boxes' are changed , all of the 'state.boxes' are changed too. i created new copy list for each of them and also new 'state' for each step before add them to 'states'.How to solve this?

Comment: If you are actually making copies, then changing one would not affect the others. Check the copy code. Make sure it is correct.

Comment: yes i'm sure it's my wrong but when i create copy list it  again refers to main 'boxes' . thank you very much.you're so good